# appengine-maven-plugin versus maven-android-plugin

Tags: google-app-engine, maven, google-cloud-endpoints, android-maven-plugin, appengine-maven-plugin

I'm trying to use Google Cloud Endpoints with Android client, built by Maven.

The problem is that appengine-maven-plugin v1.8.3+ require Maven v3.1.0+

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.appengine:appengine-maven- plugin:1.8.4:endpoints_get_discovery_doc (default) on project pro-gae: The plugin com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.8.4 requires Maven version 3.1.0 -> [Help 1]
```

while android-maven-plugin v3.6.1 doesn't (and will not) work with Maven v3.1.0 (see devs discussion at https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/issues/detail?id=395). The error

```
A required class was missing while executing com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.6.1:generate-sources: Lorg/sonatype/aether/RepositorySystem;
```

So I'm kinda locked out. One plugin asks for v3.1.0+, while the other one claims Maven 3.1.0 to be fatally buggy. So I left out to generate Endpoints client sources manually.

Any other ideas, besides waiting for fixed Maven 3.1.1? It doesn't seem to happen soon, because Maven 3.1.0 was released more than two months ago.

Comment: This question is no longer relevant as Gradle is now the recommended way to build Android apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of the Android Maven Plugin is 3.8.0 and it now requires Maven 3.1.1+. This should allow you to use the latest appengine plugin as well. And Maven 3.1.1 has been released in the meantime as well.

Update Sept 2015: Latest version of the plugin is 4.3.0 with 4.3.1 around the corner. The 4x branch works with Maven 3.0.5+ but we strongly encourage users to use the latest Maven release.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, looks resolved by just using older version (1.8.2) of appengine-maven-plugin.

Answer (score 0):

One other way of building is to configure the Run Configuration to use an external Maven Runtime.

To do this in Eclipse for Windows :
Right Click Project -> Run Configuration -> Create a new configuration -> In Main tab configure Maven Runtime.

I hope this helps.

Comment: It's not a problem with Eclipse. Problem was between plugins versions, and did not depend on whether mvn is run from IDE or command-line. Anyway, it's not relevant anymore as Gradle took of as primary way to build Android apps, so let me close the question.